# Xamarin.forms: Show a tabbedpage inside the master detail page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a master detail page. I need this, because i want the hamburger icon in the corner to open the side drawer menu.

I also have a tabbed page (With two content pages on it)

I want to combine the two:

So either having my tabbed page have a hamburg icon (instead of the back button) or having the master detail page wrap a tabbed page. (I think the second approach is the easiest.)

I didnt find any solution to this however.

How is this possible?

Thank you!

I tried to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PogoChat.Screens.Screen_MainMenu"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:PogoChat.Screens">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:Screen_MainMenuMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
            <TabbedPage>
                <TabbedPage.Children>
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 1" Icon="ja.png" />
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 2" Icon="ja.png" />
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 3" Icon="ja.png" />
                </TabbedPage.Children>
            </TabbedPage>
        </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

But this just gets rid of the burger icon even though it does show a tabbed page then...

Comment: assign your TabbedPage to the Detail property of the MasterDetail.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more ? ?:)

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Add a NavigationPage to your TabbedPage should work, you can custom the title and icon in the master page:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <app313:Page1 Title="microsoft" IconImageSource="test.png"></app313:Page1>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <TabbedPage>
                <TabbedPage.Children>
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 1" Icon="ja.png" />
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 2" Icon="ja.png" />
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 3" Icon="ja.png" />
                </TabbedPage.Children>
            </TabbedPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```